# Change default Ruby Time format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep having to append ".strftime("%H:%M")" to anything that is displaying a time in my Rails project. I have a start time and an end time for each Concert object, so I have to append ".strftime("%H:%M")" whenever I wanna display those times.

Note that I'm not asking to change the date format. The date looks fine as it is (as MM/DD/YYYY).

What's the best way to get around this? Is there a way to set the default time format?

(I'm pretty sure this is only a Ruby thing, but I'm a newbie, so I'm not sure.)

Comment: Allow me to suggest not using MM/DD/YYYY for your date format unless your site is very clearly only of use to people in the US. It's often ambiguous (e.g. 01/02/2011) and much of the rest of the world uses DD<sep>MM<sep>YYYY. Better to use a (possibly short) name for the month.

Comment: Noted! I personally use DD/MM/YYYY myself despite being in the States, but this project is for a very, very small party, all of whom are from the US and use the MM/DD convention.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you're using Rails, take advantage of the I18n support: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%H:%M"
```

Then when you call `I18n.l Time.now` or `<%= l Time.now %>`, it'll use that format automatically.

Comment: So, I might be missing something, but I've added that to the yml file, and have yet to see a change. I'm running Rails 2.3.8, and I remember having trouble with internationalization before with the Agile book. The only way I can get some translations is using the t method. From what I've read, the translations should be automatic. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: This might seem silly, but have you restarted the server? I don't think the translation files are reloaded automatically. If so, double check the syntax. YAML is very particular about the indentation. Finally, try specifying the "default" explicitly to make sure that the docs aren't incorrect in this behavior.

Comment: Hmm, I did try restarting the server, but that doesn't seem the be the problem. I'm not sure what you mean by specifying the default explicitly, though...

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails has built-in presets for formatting `Date` and `Time` instances. Here's what they are for `Time` on my machine:

```
>> Time::DATE_FORMATS
=> {:short=>"%d %b %H:%M", :db=>"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", :rfc822=>#<Proc:0x0000000103700b08@/Users/donovan/.gem/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/conversions.rb:13>, :time=>"%H:%M", :number=>"%Y%m%d%H%M%S", :long_ordinal=>#<Proc:0x0000000103700e50@/Users/donovan/.gem/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/conversions.rb:12>, :long=>"%B %d, %Y %H:%M"}
```

You can easily use them like so:

```
>> Time.now.to_s(:db)
=> "2011-01-12 15:26:11"
```

You can define your own and use it, too:

```
>> Time::DATE_FORMATS[:mine] = "%H:%M"
=> "%H:%M"
>> Time.now.to_s(:mine)
=> "15:28"
```

Comment: Where should I put "Time::DATE_FORMATS[:mine] = "%H:%M""? What version of Ruby/Rails are you using? I get "NameError: uninitialized constant Time::DATE_FORMATS" in irb when I try that.

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.0.1 in the app I tested it in. You should take @coreyward's suggestion to add it to the locale config.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom function in your application_helper.rb file. Maybe something like:

```
def custom_time(date)
  date.strftime("%H:%M")
end
```

Not sure if this is best practice but it should work well.

Answer (score 0):

I use an initializer: config/initializers/time_formats.rb which contains:

```
[Time, Date].map do |klass|
  klass::DATE_FORMATS[:app_date] = "%m/%d/%Y"
  klass::DATE_FORMATS[:app_month_and_year] = "%B %Y"
  klass::DATE_FORMATS[:app_abbrev_month_and_year] = "%b %Y"
  ...
end
```

Then I use Time.now.to_s(:app_date), etc based on how I want to display it. 
You could add `Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%H:%M"` to accomplish what you're trying to do. This is not internationalized though - for that, coreyward's answer is probably better.