# Change date format in the view to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date-format

The default date format in Ruby is yyyy-mm-dd, but I needed them to be dd/mm/yyyy in the view

I have wrote a date_format file in `config/initializers` as:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!( :uk_format => '%m/%d/%Y')
```

This didn't work since I need to call `date.to_s(:uk_format)` in order to use this format. But since I'm using `<%= f.text_field :paymentDate %>` to display the date, I'm not sure I can add `to_s` to this case.

Can someone help me out please.

---

**Edit 1**

Actually date.to_s(:uk_format) doesn't work either, how do I use initializer properly.....?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See: [Change default Ruby Time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675189/change-default-ruby-time-format/4675236#4675236)

Adapted my answer linked to above for the Date and format specified:

---

Since you're using Rails, take advantage of the I18n support: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%m/%Y"
```

Then you can call `I18n.l Date.today` to get out a formatted date. Or in your view, you can use `<%= l @foo.created_at %>`.

Comment: What about calling date from database, does this gets effected as well?

Comment: As an output helper, I18n will work on whatever data you give it, regardless the source, so yes, it works fine for displaying dates from the database. It's a really bad idea to transform dates into display format for storage, though, if that's what you mean.

Comment: What about getting that default date format reflected in form fields (e.g. when editing a date attribute on a model)?

Comment: @findchris That's a totally separate question, and I bet it's been answered on here before, but if you can't find it, ask it. ;)

Comment: As for me, Rails 3.2.13 and created_at, I had to use en: time: ... instead of en: date:

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!({:db => '%m/%d/%Y', :uk_format => '%m/%d/%Y'})
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!({:db => '%m/%d/%Y', :uk_format => '%m/%d/%Y'})
```