# Date format in view returning unexpected format; correct format in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date

I am trying to format my dates in the YYYY-MMM-DD manner.  I have a en.yml file that has it specified.

```
formats:
  default: ! '%Y-%b-%d'
```

I have also created a date_time_formats.rb in my initializers folder.

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%Y-%b-%d'
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:db]= '%Y-%b-%d'
```

I have also tried placing the same code directly in my `environments.rb` file.  If I test out the defaults in the console `Date.now.to_s` then I get what I expect in return, "2012-Nov-10", but in my view I always see "2012-11-10".

I have tried saving it in the controller with `Date.now` and `Date.now.to_s`, but I still get the same result.

I must be missing something simple, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, although I dont understand why.  Here is a Stack answer that explains it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303495/change-date-format-in-the-view-to-dd-mm-yyyy?lq=1)

Basically I added these 2 lines of code to my environment.rb.

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!({:db => '%m/%d/%Y', :uk_format => '%m/%d/%Y'})
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!({:db => '%m/%d/%Y', :uk_format => '%m/%d/%Y'})
```

And now everything works as planned.  I looked for the documentation on the merge function to get a better understanding, but did not have any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to localize your dates in the view:

```
<%= l(Model.created_at) %>
```

Comment: Can you do this in a form with a f.text_field type tag?