# Submitting dates in US format: mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I can get Rails to display mm/dd/yyyy using the following initializer:

date_format.rb

```
 Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%m/%d/%Y"
```

or l18n using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5303521/1261474)

But this does not change the way dates are submitted.  When submitted:

```
10/02/2014
```

Will be parsed as

```
 @entry.photo_date
 Mon, 10 Feb 2014
```

I'm looking for a way to submit a date in mm/dd/yyyy format.

I'd like to be able to do this centrally, so I do not have to repeat code throughout the application

Comment: @njzk2 i already saw that post, it shows how to format dates the way mine are formatted now, not how to format them in mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: and you can't adapt that answer to your format?

Comment: I've already tried, as you see above.  @njzk2

Comment: Try using I18n, like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5303521/1261474) suggests.

Comment: I've updated my question.  Linked answers work for displaying `%m/%d/%Y` correctly, but date submission still parses in the manner noted in my question.  I read all of the answers and couldn't find it, or am I missing something?

Comment: @jamesdlivesinatree: ok, so the issue is with date typed as text and submitted. I think the specific format here would vary depending on the locale of the client, wouldn't it? I think it would help if you detailed how the date is inputed.

Comment: @njzk2 As of now, it is a standard input box.  As in, the client is instructed to write the date as `mm/dd/yyyy`.  When the user inputs, it is parsed as `dd/mm/yyyy`.  I have modified the l18n like you suggested, maybe there's a way to dictate this within there?

Comment: Why is this question marked as duplicate?  The linked question is about displaying dates, not accepting them as input.  @jamesdlivesinatree, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Reopened and answered the actual question, also changed the title to make it clearer that you were talking about submitting dates, not displaying them.

Answer (score 5):

In modern ruby (ie. with `prepend`) you can insert your own type casting in front of Rails's.  You'll want to do this for whatever other date/time formats you're using.  Here's the code for `Date`, just stick this in an `config/initializers/typecasts.rb` or somewhere:

```
module Typecasting
  module Date
    def cast_value v
      ::Date.strptime v, "%m/%d/%Y" rescue super
    end  
  end  

  ::ActiveRecord::Type::Date.prepend Date
end
```

Rails will try the American format and fall back to using the builtin method if that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
irb(main):001:0> today = Date.today
=> Tue, 06 Jan 2015
irb(main):003:0> today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
=> "01/06/2015"
```

So in your case, `@entry.photo_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")` should work.

Comment: this probably works, but i'm looking for a way to do this in an initializer.  I do not want to convert dates throughout my application